# How do I specify in KML a min/max altitude of spherical bubble around a certain location

Tags: java, google-maps, kml

I need to specify an min/max altitude around a sphere around a certain location. How do a specify a spherical bubble around using the following KML

```
                    kmlData.append("  <open>1</open>");


                    kmlData.append("  <Folder>");

                    kmlData.append("    <Style id=\"alertStyle\">");
                    kmlData.append("      <IconStyle>");
                    kmlData.append("        <color>ff0000ff</color>");
                    kmlData.append("        <colorMode>normal</colorMode>");
                    kmlData.append("        <Icon>");
                    kmlData.append("          <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/placemark_circle.png</href>");
                    kmlData.append("          <scale>1.0</scale>");
                    kmlData.append("        </Icon>");
                    kmlData.append("      </IconStyle>");
                    kmlData.append("    </Style>");
                    kmlData.append("    <Style id=\"ownshipBubbleStyle\">");
                    kmlData.append("      <PolyStyle>");
                    kmlData.append("        <color>9900ffff</color>");
                    kmlData.append("        <colorMode>normal</colorMode>");
                    kmlData.append("        <fill>1</fill>");
                    kmlData.append("        <outline>0</outline>");
                    kmlData.append("      </PolyStyle>");
                    kmlData.append("    </Style>");
                    kmlData.append("    <name>"+getName()+"</name>");
                    kmlData.append("    <description>"+getDescription()+"</description>");
                    kmlData.append("    <open>1</open>");
                    kmlData.append(getAsAsKml());
                    kmlData.append("  </Folder>");

                    kmlData.append("</Document>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/models) says: "In KML, you can import 3D models - such as buildings, bridges, monuments, and statues - in the COLLADA interchange file format".

So you need to create a 3D model of a sphere (like [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/schmist/Jemula802/master/resources/models/sphere.dae)), import it into kml and specify the altitude element of the model)

[image: 3d sphere in kml]

Comment: the min and max altitude will always different so I cannot just a static oject. actually it be more of a cylinder